# error package org.python.util does not exist, compilation with ant

Tags: java, python, import, compiler-errors

I am trying to call a python method in java, similar functionality as [Unresolved import org.python / working with jython and java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179009/unresolved-import-org-python-working-with-jython-and-java)

However, I am using ant to compile and run my files. using `import org.python.util` will give me this error

```
package org.python.util does not exist
```

I can see that python.org.util exists in jython-2.5.0.jar.

So, here is the class path I have in my build.xml ant file:

```
classpath="${java.class.path}:./jgrapht/lib/jgrapht-jdk1.5.jar:\
    ./jgrapht/lib/jgraph.jar:./jgraphx/lib/jgraphx.jar:\
    ./jython/lib/jython-2.5.0.jar:./colt/lib/colt.jar:."
```

and I also I added the path to jython jar files to my class path. i.e. looks like `echo $path` gives me all the required paths. Is there anything missing here that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to make all classes in the package available:

```
import org.python.util.*;
```

Or this to include a particular class:

```
import org.python.util.TemplateAntTask;
```

EDIT: Also, looks like there is an extra slash after jython-2.5.0.jar in your classpath.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I made the modifications based on your suggestion. However, I still get "package org.python.util does not exist
    [javac] import org.python.util.*;
"

Comment: Try to compile one very basic java class with import of python: "javac -cp yourclasspath YourClass.java". Make sure this works. Also, post your ant script.

Comment: I tried to compile a basic code based on your suggestion. If I use javac -cp myclasspath myclass.java it compiles just fine. however, javac myclass.java does not compile and I get the same error as before. Also when I echo $path I do see the correct class path!

Comment: You have to use correct classpath for java to compile/run properly. Do not confuse it with OS shell path. Make sure that classpath is specified correctly in you ant script. Check [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) article.